# Convert SplFileInfo to String

Tags: php, class, object

I'm using a DirectoryIterator to get a folder's contents, and it works just fine :

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . $this->certificate), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    array_push($files, $value);
}
unset($value);
```

But my `$files` result when printed it isn't a string but a STD Class. How could I convert that output as a string ( in case there's only one file ) or to an array ?

**EDIT :** This would be the result I get :

```
{ [0]=> object(SplFileInfo)#5 (2) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(101) "C:\Users\rgr\Apache\htdocs\Roland Groza [ 3.0 ]\class\mongohq/certificate\GTECyberTrustGlobalRoot.crt" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(27) "GTECyberTrustGlobalRoot.crt" } }
```

Comment: Btw, there's a big difference between stdClass and something like SplFileInfo :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$value` is instance of [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php), if u need filename push `$key` or `$value->__toString()` to `$files`

Answer (score 1):

use this function to convert from std class object to array

```
 function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}

 $arr = objectToArray(files);
 print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I just get an empty array, I tried it before, the function above, I got it from the PHP Manual

Comment: The goal is not to convert any object to an array; it's about converting an object to its string representation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `$files` seems to be an array in your example. You are pushing values onto it.

As for converting a `stdClass` to array you can convert it by casting:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$arr = (array) $obj;
```

You can also do it the other way around:

```
$arr = array();
$obj = (object) $arr;
```

If you want a string out of an object or an array then you need to dereference it:

```
$str = $arr['key'];
$str = $obj->property;
```

Does this answer your question or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be [type casting](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) (more specific [array casting](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)):

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->bar = 'baz';
$foo->boo = 'far';
$arr = (array)$foo;
var_dump($arr);
/*
array(2) {
  ["bar"]=>
  string(3) "baz"
  ["boo"]=>
  string(3) "far"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
array_push((array)$files, $value);
```

But if $files have multi std class, use Yogesh suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iterator_to_array()` coupled with `array_keys()`.

```
print_r(array_keys(iterator_to_array($iterator)));
```

By default, the flags of `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` are:

```
FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME
FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
```

Which uses the current file name as the iterator key and an instance of `SplFileInfo` as the iterator value.